Why is my GridDB query so slow when pulling data from a TimeSeries container over a large date range
So, I’m using GridDB to store sensor data in a TimeSeries container, with each entry having a timestamp, temperature, and humidity value. The problem is that when I try to run queries to pull data over larger date ranges (like a week or a month), it’s taking way longer than I expected.
Here’s an example of what my query looks like:
from griddb_python import *
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

DB_HOST = "127.0.0.1:10001"
DB_CLUSTER = "myCluster"
DB_USER = "admin"
DB_PASS = "admin"

factory = StoreFactory.get_instance()

# Connect GridDB
gridstore = factory.get_store(
    notification_member=DB_HOST, cluster_name=DB_CLUSTER, username=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS)

# get container and run the query
container = gridstore.get_container("sensor_data")
end_time = datetime.now()
start_time = end_time - timedelta(days=7)

query = container.query(f"SELECT * WHERE timestamp BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('{start_time.isoformat()}') AND TIMESTAMP('{end_time.isoformat()}')")
rs = query.fetch()

# results
while rs.has_next():
    data = rs.next()
    print(data)


I know the container has a lot of data (millions of rows), and I think that’s slowing things down. Is there a way to make this faster? Should I be doing something like indexing or another way to handle large datasets more efficiently in GridDB?
